# Django group by date and count per category

Tags: python, mysql, django

Example models

```
class Category(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()

class CategoryItem(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField()
    quantity = models.IntField()
    at = models.DateTimeField()


Categories:
    1, Category #1
    2, Category #2
    3, Category #3

Items:
    ID,NAME,CATEGORY_ID,QUANTITY,AT
    1,Item #1,1,100,2017.1.1
    2,Item #2,1,200,2017.1.3
    3,Item #3,1,300,2017.1.3
    4,Item #4,2,400,2017.1.10
    5,Item #5,3,500,2017.1.10
```

How i can annotate this by day and count "quantity" per category

Like this

```
 2017.1.1
    - Category #1
        - Quantity: 100

2017.1.3
    - Category #1
        - Quantity: 500

2017.1.10
    - Category #2
        - Quantity: 400
    - Category #3
        - Quantity: 500
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_.

It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Maybe you expected a free code writing service here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want a Django query with group by and count (and inner join).

Try something like this:

```
CategoryItem.objects.filter(CategoryItem__Category__isnull=False).values('at,name').annotate(total=Count('quantity')).order_by('at')
```